# Oil burner water leak

Tags: leak

My oil burner is leaking water out the box that contains the sparking gun. It's like a faucet thats left just on. Theres a hissing sound of water leaking. I'm thinking it's a plumbing issue but am not sure. Help!
Matthew

Comment: If it is not a hot water tank, you have big problems.  If a hot water tank, it is time for replacement.

Comment: Some photos would probably be helpful.  As it is it's anyone's guess.

Comment: Shut off the oil burner shutoff switch that's normally required in some obvious location with a bright red labeled switchplate by any normal code, and **call for service**, as it does not seem particularly likely for you to be able to solve this one yourself. Do check that it's water, not oil, but check after you shut it down. Either way is a problem, if it's oil and not shut down burning your house down is a major risk.

Comment: Is this oil burner in a *furnace* or in a *boiler*?

Comment: At a minimum, listing the make/model of the equipment in question will help you get an answer, as would pictures of the leak location. However, I've got to agree, despite this being a DIY site, you're probably best off shutting it down _now_ and calling in professional help on this one. Sometimes, that's the best, fastest, safest, cheapest answer.